# C# WinForms Webbrowser Getelementbyid

Tags: javascript, html

```
  <div id="test">test content1</div>
some htmlcode
  <div id="test">test content2</div>
 some html code
   <div id="test">test content3</div>
```

`document.getElementById("test").InnerText`

output is

```
test content1
```

how to access the second and third div innertext as above ?

Edit:id cannot be unique.because this code written by outlook web mail.
I need  access programmatically second mails content.
Mails format :
             Sender1
            Sender2
            Sender3
             Sender4
i say again this code from Microsoft Outlook Web App

Comment: Welcome to **stackoverflow**, we **do not** code for you. Read: [how to ask a question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: I would suggest you to use `HtmlAgilityPack` https://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/

Comment: an id should be unique. Use a class if you want to re-use css styles.

Answer (score 1):

You need different Ids for your elements. So to be able to call each differently:

```
 <div id="test1">test content1</div>
some htmlcode
  <div id="test2">test content2</div>
 some html code
   <div id="test3">test content3</div>
```

Usage:

```
document.getElementById("test1").InnerText 
document.getElementById("test2").InnerText 
document.getElementById("test3").InnerText
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  int i=0; 
  List<HtmlElement> list= new List<HtmlElement>();
              foreach (  HtmlElement item in   document.GetElementsByTagName("div"))
            {
                if (i < 3)
                {

                    if (item.GetAttribute("id") == "divSenderList")
                    {
                        list.Add(item);
                        i++;
                        MessageBox.Show(item.InnerHtml);

                    }


                }
                else
                    break;
```